# How to create a label with buttons in mapview

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview

I am VERY new to iphone but what i am trying to accomplish is when you open the app it shows a mapview on Home screen with flat location.if i click flat ,i want to show nearest restuarents with in some radius.

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom annotation instead of this, because it is clickable to action

https://github.com/akshay1188/CustomAnnotation

https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview